# How to sort the numbers without repeating in the next line in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

This is my code and this is wrong

```
i = ''
for a in range (1,37):
    i += str(a)+' '
    print(i)
```

This is the output i want

[image: This is the output i want]

Comment: This code has syntax errors. What is `for b in range` supposed to do?

Comment: Your question had nothing to do with Jupyter or `while` loops for that matter, so I removed those tags. Please provide a code example that has its obvious syntax errors fixed and is a genuine attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Selcuk i'm sorry, i fixed it

Comment: @Grismar i'm sorry bro, im will fix it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can also do it like this:-**

```py
n=1
for i in range(8):
    for j in range (i+1):
        print(n,end=' ')
        n += 1
    print()
```

Comment: I like this one, it looks simple and easy to understand, Thank you sir for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way:**

```py
def contnum(n):
    num = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print(num, end=" ")
            num = num + 1
            print("\r")
         
n = 5       
contnum(n)
```

Comment: First of all, the indentation is completely messed up. BTW, this code won't print anything. So, there will no output.

Comment: why that so it prints the way...as asked

Comment: Have you tested this yourself?

Comment: yeah, I have tested.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `itertools.count`:

```py
import itertools

n = 8
c = itertools.count(start=1)

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(' '.join(str(next(c)) for _ in range(i)))
```

(Actually you don't need `join`; you can just use unpacking: `print(*(next(c) for _ in range(i)))`)

If you don't want to import a module, but you are willing to use walrus operator (python 3.8+),

```py
n = 8
c = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(*(c := c + 1 for _ in range(i)))
```

Output:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

Comment: What is the ( _ ) symbol for sir?

Comment: @Sennayga It's just throwing away the value; you can just replace it with any other insignificant letter, such as `x`. This value won't be used anyways. For example, `[[] for _ in range(3)]` will result in `[[], [], []]`, which is a good trick to initialize a list of empty lists, by the way. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Comment: Aaah i see, and what is the word "join" for ?

Comment: @Sennayga `', '.join(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charles'])` will result in `'Alice, Bob, Charles'`; i.e., it joins a list of strings into a string, putting a specified string between them. In this case, the 'in-between' string is a blank `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

```
limit,a, k = 37,1, 1
while a < limit:
    print(' '.join(str(x) for x in range(a, min(a + k,limit))))
    a += k
    k += 1
```

Output:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `itertools.islice` and `count`, and `iter`'s sentinel:

```
it = iter(range(1, 37))
n = count(1)
f = lambda : list(islice(it, next(n)))
list(iter(f, []))
```

Output:

```
[[1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
 [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
 [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]]
```

Or if you want to `print`:

```
for i in iter(f, []):
    print(*i)
```

Output:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

Answer (score 0):

My entry for code golf:

```
for n in range(1, 9):
    print(*range(1+n*(n-1)//2, 1+n*(n+1)//2))
```

produces the expected outcome.